# Meteor - file download with meteor-files package ( ostrio:files)

Tags: meteor

I would need some help with meteor-files package 
I'm following the simplest-download DEMO here https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/tree/master/demo-simplest-download-button  and getting on a few bumpers. First here is the code:

```
this.Books = new Meteor.Files({
  debug: true,
  collectionName: 'Books'
});

// To have sample file in DB we will upload it on server startup:
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Books.denyClient();
  Books.collection.attachSchema(Books.schema);

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (true) {
      Books.load('http://localhost:3000/file.pdf', {
        fileName: 'file.pdf',
        meta: {}
      });
    }
  });

  Meteor.publish('Books', function () {
    return Books.find().cursor;
  });

} else {

  Meteor.subscribe('Books');
}
```

1. Problem - When I c/p the code from the git then there is this condition if

> (!Images.find().count())

which meteor just doesn't recognize as a function and breaks there. I fixed that with just replacing it with TRUE as you can see in code

2. Problem is that now everything runs and my file is successfuly imported but I can see in the server log that he is not able to find the file resulting in:

   [FilesCollection] [load] Received: http://localhost:3000/file.pdf
   I20160806-14:00:27.190(2)? [FilesCollection] [load] [insert] file.pdf -> Books
   I20160806-14:00:29.360(2)? [FilesCollection] [find(undefined)]
   I20160806-14:00:33.045(2)? [FilesCollection] [find(undefined)]

Answer (score 1):

The package was out of date and needed a meteor update from my side. If someone will need